# Performing performItemClick

Tags: android, android-listview

I recently figured out how to instantiate a `ListView`, and using `onAnimationEnd` and `performItemClick`, I was able to click the first item in the `ListView` programmatically.

This solution works wonderfully, but my problem is that if the `ListView` contains too many items to fit on the screen, other items in the `ListView` are selected instead (not even just one). Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?

```
@Override
public Animation onCreateAnimation(int transit, boolean enter, int nextAnim) {
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), nextAnim);

        anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                mListView.performItemClick(mListView, 0, mListView.getItemIdAtPosition(0));
            }
        });
        return anim;
    } else {
        return super.onCreateAnimation(transit, enter, nextAnim);
    }
}
```

Comment: issue with view recycling. post your adapter.

Comment: new SimpleCursorAdapter(mContext, R.layout.biditems_row, null, from, to, 0);  ...?

Comment: I think you may be right. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513726/same-view-jumps-around-in-listview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
mListView.performItemClick(mListView.getAdapter().getView(your_click_position, null, null), your_click_position, mListView.getItemIdAtPosition(your_click_position));
```

Or

```
mListView.performItemClick(mListView.getChildAt(your_click_position), your_click_position, mListView.getItemIdAtPosition(your_click_position));
```

instead of

```
mListView.performItemClick(mListView, 0, mListView.getItemIdAtPosition(0));
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: you are passing 0 hard coded, hence if you scroll down the list it will cause problem because of the view recycling in listview,hence if you pass the position of item clicked, it will work.

Comment: Ah, seems that I didn't really understand how ListViews work. Please take a look at my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513726/same-view-jumps-around-in-listview