# Same View jumps around in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView with several Views in each row. I change the background of one of these Views when the row is clicked. As I scroll through the ListView, it seems that this highlighted View is reused in other rows, thus I have a highlighted View in rows that I do not want it in. Could someone explain why this happens and a possible fix? Thanks

Comment: Refer this http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/

Comment: You can search google for The world of ListView by Romain Guy.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using baseAdapter to inflate your ListView?

If yes, then it may be a case of convertView and position changeing everytime you scroll.